# Return laravel view from JavaScript Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, web

I'm having trouble trying to show the view I want after calling the controller method from Ajax.

This is the JavaScript function where I call the controller Method 'create_pedido' with an Ajax post.

```js
$('.small-box').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let camarero_id = document.getElementById('id_camarero').value;
    let mesa_id = e.currentTarget.parentElement.attributes.idMesa.value;
    let mesa_estado = e.currentTarget.parentElement.attributes.disponible.value;
    console.log('ID Mesa: ' + mesa_id);
    console.log('Disponible: ' + mesa_estado);
    console.log('ID Camarero: ' + camarero_id);
    if (mesa_estado == 1) {
        console.log('Crear')
        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            type: "POST",
            url: 'create_pedido',
            data: { mesa: mesa_id, camarero: camarero_id }
        }).done(function(msg) {
            console.log('Success');
        });
    } else {
        console.log('Editar')
    }
});
```

This is the controller method which does everything but returning the view where it should go after.

```php
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $mesa = Mesa::find($request->mesa);
    $camarero = Trabajador::find($request->camarero);
    $alimentos = Alimento::all();
    $categorias = Categoria::all();
    Log::channel('stderr')->info($mesa);
    Log::channel('stderr')->info($camarero);
    return view('pedido.create', compact('mesa', 'camarero','categorias', 'alimentos'));
}
```

Instead of going to the 'pedidos.create' view after the 'Log::channel...' stay in the same view where it was called.

Here are my routes:

```
Route::resource('/', 'IndexController');
Route::resource('inicio', 'IndexController');
Route::resource('trabajador', 'TrabajadorController');
Route::resource('pedido', 'PedidoController');
Route::post('create_pedido','PedidoController@create');
Route::resource('alimento', 'AlimentoController');
Route::resource('orden', 'OrdenController');
Route::resource('mesa', 'MesaController');
Route::post('mesa_changestate', 'MesaController@change_state');
```

Answer (score 0):

Its likely returning to the same view because you are not telling it the base URL of the app.  Laravel has a nice method to help here, which will prepend the route with the appropriate base:

```
$.ajax({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    type: "POST",
    url: '{{url("create_pedido")}}', // use blade to add in the Laravel url() method here
    data: { mesa: mesa_id, camarero: camarero_id }
}).
```

Also for the return statement in the controller `create` method - is the folder 'pedido' or 'pedidos' - make sure to call the right view :)

Comment: I'm not sure of what do you mean with "use blade to add in the Laravel url() method here" and I've realize the problem is that when I return the view comes back to the .done(msg) instead of going to the browser

Comment: If it is getting to the done method - I think everything is working fine.  The `url()` method is a Laravel helper to prefix the correct base URL.  I just meant using blade's `{{}}` will allow you to access the php underneath.  If you are getting to the `.done(msg)`, you just need to add JS code within that message to display it on your page.  If you are expecting a fresh page load, then have an `<a>` link rather than ajax.  Ajax will look for code to load *without* going to refresh the page or going to a different page.